# display a success message on different portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have form on a porlet, after submission of that form, page is redirecting to another portlet for that i am using `actionResponse.sendRedirect("/abc/bcd/newWebPage")`
and i am landing on to different page. One that page the same potlet is added with different screen, Now i want to display a success message on next page.

for that i am using portlet session and passing parameter to jsp.

```
PortletSession session = actionRequest.getPortletSession();
                            session.setAttribute("SUCCESSA", "Successfully",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

But its not working.

Any help how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

When you say `One that page the same potlet is added with different screen`, I understand that you have another instance of the same portlet in different page. By the way, you haven't explained what is not working for you. I assume you are wondering how to read in the JSP page. It's pretty straight forward:

**In Controller:**

```
PortletUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, "SUCCESSA", "Successfully", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

**In JSP:**

```
pageContext.setAttribute("succcessa", PortletUtils.getSessionAttribute(renderRequest, "SUCCESSA", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE));
```

The `PortletUtils` does the same as setting the attribute using the `PortletRequest` object but its preferrable.

**To remove the session attribute:**

```
PortletUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, "SUCCESSA", null, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

The implementation of PortletUtils is that it removes the session attribute if value is null, if a session existed at all.

Comment: Actually the parameter has passed successfully but the issue was facing was 'based on passed param i was displaying some message' even after destroying the session after displaying with `actionRequest.getPortletSession().removeAttribute("attributeName",scopeId);` the attribute was remain showing. So i have used HttpSession and passed the att in jsp and after displaying the message, `session.removeAttribute("Attribute");` worked fine for me.

Comment: Just because `PortletSession` doesn't work for you, you shouldn't use `HttpSession`.  They both serve a different purpose.  PortletSession is essentially a layer of abstraction on top of HttpSession to control portlet level permissions. So, you have to find why `removeAttribute` is not working for you. I think you are not using the right scope while removing. Try `PortletUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, "SUCCESSA", null, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);`